Ubuntu 24.04 + Intellij Idea Community Edition 2024.2.3 There are no settings for allowing access to removable media
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 + Intellij Idea Community Edition 2024.2.3. There are no settings for allowing access to removable media. After a number of updates, the settings for access to an additional HDD drive (access to removable media) disappeared. Everything works in other applications.

For example, in other applications:

